# Why did the author choose 3 min 4 sec to be stolen by the Sídhe?

Tags: mythology, fairy, the-grey-land, peader-o-guilin

In Peadar Ó Guilín's the Call series, why did the author choose for the Sídhe to steal teenagers away to the Grey Land for exactly 3 minutes and 4 seconds? Was this length of time, or proportion of a day, chosen because of some kind of mythological resonance? Or is it just a random short length of time?

Comment: Are you interested in the *in-universe* reason (i.e. why this amount of time in the context of the story) or just the out-of-universe reason for the author's decision?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - OP's acceptance of my answer would seem to suggest that my initial reading (that they were interested in why the author chose the time out-of-universe) was accurate.

Comment: I (OP) was interested in what mythological or calculated percentage the author based the time on, yes. I wasn't sure how much the reasoning would be in-universe and how much out-of-universe, since his fantasy universe has such deep roots in myths and religious beliefs of ancient people. Turns out he just went with what felt right - not the most satisfying answer, but a definitive one, which means I can stop looking for time references in fairy tales to try to find the answer. Thank you for a very useful and quick sourced answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author answered the out-of-universe reasoning in a series of tweets in 2016.

> **Q.** *How long is a day in  the Grey Lands? Also **why is it 3 mins and 4 seconds**?*
>
> **PÓG:** *Nobody really knows. It feels like a day, but is it? 3 minutes and 4 seconds was a decision I made because **I wanted it to be long
> enough for tension to form, but not so long for tension to run out...**
> Not a good answer, I know ;)*
>
> <sub><sup>Per Twitter [1](https://twitter.com/TheCallYA/status/811645600227676160), [2](https://twitter.com/TheCallYA/status/811645831963086849) - Edited for readability</sup></sub>

In universe, the amount of time was because the Sídhe don't use *human* time measurements.

> **Q.** *"3 minutes and 4 seconds" seems very precise. Was there a specific reason this amount of time was chosen by you?*
>
> **PÓG:** *Not really. I didn't want it to be exactly three minutes, because, why would the Sídhe use our measurements of time? That's all*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/TheCallYA/status/1114963963698130944)</sup></sub>

Comment: Boiling an egg?

Comment: @DannyMcG - Sure, if you're really keen to have a runny undercooked egg